# Como formatar um número em porcentagem dentro do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sql, jsp, porcentagem

Senhores, estou desenvolvendo um painel de monitoramento de faturamento. Quero transformar esse número em 56% diretamente no meu código do JavaScript. Segue um trecho do meu código, ele é alimentado diretamente por uma query do meu SQL.

Essa é a query que alimenta meu campo dentro do JavaScript, a variável `MT` recebe ela.

```
<snk:query var="MT">

        SELECT
            A.REALIZADO,
            A.META,
            (A.REALIZADO/A.META)*100 AS ACUMULADO

            FROM (

            SELECT 
            ((SELECT ISNULL(SUM((ITE1.QTDNEG*ITE1.VLRUNIT)-ITE1.VLRDESC-ITE1.VLRREPRED),0)
             FROM SANKHYA.TGFCAB CAB1 (NOLOCK)
             LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.TGFITE   ITE1 (NOLOCK) ON ITE1.NUNOTA=CAB1.NUNOTA
             LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.TGFPRO   PRO1 (NOLOCK) ON ITE1.CODPROD = PRO1.CODPROD
             WHERE CAB1.TIPMOV = 'V'
             AND   MONTH(CAB1.DTFATUR)= DATEPART(MM,GETDATE())
             AND   YEAR (CAB1.DTFATUR)= DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())
             AND   ITE1.CODCFO IN (5102,5403,5405,5922,6102,6108,6110,6403,6404,6922)
             AND   CAB1.STATUSNFE <> 'D'
             AND   PRO1.AD_MARCA=14 ) -
            (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),ISNULL(SUM((ITE1.QTDNEG*ITE1.VLRUNIT)-ITE1.VLRDESC-ITE1.VLRREPRED) ,0))
             FROM SANKHYA.TGFCAB CAB1 (NOLOCK)
             LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.TGFITE   ITE1 (NOLOCK) ON ITE1.NUNOTA=CAB1.NUNOTA 
             LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.TGFPRO   PRO1 (NOLOCK) ON ITE1.CODPROD = PRO1.CODPROD
             WHERE CAB1.TIPMOV = 'D'
             AND   MONTH(CAB1.DTFATUR)= DATEPART(MM,GETDATE())
             AND   YEAR (CAB1.DTFATUR)= DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())
             AND   ITE1.CODCFO IN (1202,1411,2202,2204,2411)
             AND   CAB1.STATUSNOTA = 'L'
             AND   PRO1.AD_MARCA=14)) AS REALIZADO,

             (SELECT DISTINCT 
              MET.PREVREC AS META_VN
              FROM SANKHYA.TGMMET MET
              LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.TGFPRO   PRO (NOLOCK) ON PRO.MARCA = MET.MARCA
              WHERE   MONTH(MET.DTREF)= DATEPART(MM,GETDATE())
              AND     YEAR (MET.DTREF)= DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())
              AND     PRO.AD_MARCA = 14) AS META
            )A

        </snk:query>
```

Trecho de código no JavaScript:

```
<div class="squareWhite" style="width:380px; font-size: 20px; height: 160px;">
                    APPLE<br></br>
                    META: <c:out value="${AP.rows[0].META}"/><br></br>
                    REALIZADO: <c:out value="${AP.rows[0].REALIZADO}" + "%"/><br></br>
                    ACUMULADO: <c:out value="${AP.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" /> //ESSE CAMPO DEVERIA RECEBER A PORCENTAGEM 
                </div>
```

Resultado:

```
REALIZADO   META        ACUMULADO
5641673,96  12500000,00 45,13339168
```

O Acumulado deveria retornar como 45%.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Complemento: código no Javascript                                                               
 <div class="squareWhite" style="width:380px; font-size: 20px; height: 160px;">
     MOTOROLA <br></br>
     META: <c:out value="${MT.rows[0].META}"/><br></br>
     REALIZADO: <c:out value="${MT.rows[0].REALIZADO}" /><br></br>
     ACUMULADO: <c:out value="${MT.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />
    </div>

Comment: Seria interessante você dá uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como funcionam as coisas por aqui!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Formas de arredondamento

Primeiro você tem que ter em mente que há várias formas possíveis de arredondar-se um número. Vejo que no seu código, você usa SQL, JavaScript e também Java visto que está usando JSTL, então vou considerar as formas de arredondar existentes nessas três linguagens. Considerando que seus números são sempre positivos, você provavelmente vai querer uma das seguintes formas:

- Para cima, em direção ao +∞: 2,1, 2,5 e 2,9 são arredondados para 3. 3,5 é arredondado para 4. Em JavaScript e Java é `Math.floor(x)`. Em SQL é `FLOOR(x)`.
- Para baixo, em direção ao -∞: 2,1, 2,5 e 2,9 são arredondados para 2. 3,5 é arredondado para 3. Em JavaScript e Java é `Math.ceil(x)`. Em SQL é `CEIL(x)`.
- Para o inteiro mais próximo, com empates em direção ao +∞: 2,1 é arredondado para 2. 2,5 e 2,9 são arredondados para 3. 3,5 é arredondado para 4. Em JavaScript e Java é `Math.round(x)`. Em SQL é `ROUND(x)`.

Há outras formas de arredondamento além dessas, especialmente no que concerne a regras de desempate (em direção a +∞, -∞, par mais próximo, ímpar mais próximo, ou alguma outra coisa) e a números negativos (se usam regras iguais ou inversas aos positivos), mas eu acho improvável que alguma dessas outras formas seja a que você quer.

## Solução no SQL

A forma mais fácil de resolver isso é arredondar no próprio SQL:

```sql
ROUND((A.REALIZADO / A.META) * 100) AS ACUMULADO
```

No lugar de `ROUND`, você pode usar `CEIL` ou `FLOOR` se preferir.

Se você não quer utilizar a solução via SQL porque você não pode por algum motivo alterar a SQL, e deseja uma solução que realmente esteja no JavaScript ou no JSP, então deixe um comentário.